# Latex: listings does not replace special characters correctly

Tags: python, latex, listings

I want to include python scripts in a document, but in those scripts I use characters like á é í ó ú. I am using the literate option of `\lstet`. Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{listings, pythonhighlight}
\lstset{ 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,        
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=false, 
    literate= {á}{{\'a}}1 
    {é}{{\'e}}1 
    {í}{{\'i}}1 
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Python]{example.py}
\end{document}
```

With a python script (example.py) that contains:

```
# coding = utf-8
# á é í ó ú
```

I get a pdf like this:

[image: pdf I get]

where all special characters are substituted by the last one in the literate option.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

Using the package `listingsutf8` instead of `listings` with

```
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,        
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=false, 
    literate= {á}{{\'a}}1 
    {é}{{\'e}}1 
    {í}{{\'i}}1 
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
}
```

does NOT change anything.
Using `listingsutf8` with:

```
\lstset{ ...
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
   ...
}
```

allows for all the special characters I need but misplaces them (all of them appear at the beginning of the python comment and not in the place they should be in the sentence).

Using `listingsutf8` with:

```
\lstset{ ...      
    inputencoding=latin1,
...
}
```

does not work either because my code is utf8, so it gives me errors compiling.

Comment: This may help you: [How to insert code with accents with listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-to-insert-code-with-accents-with-listings/85947)

Comment: None of the solutions there seem to work. The ones that use the `literate` option give me the same problem. The one that uses the package `listingsutf8` with the option `inputencoding=utf8/latin1` misplaces the special characters and the ones that only use `inputencoding=latin1` do not compile because my code is utf-8. It seems that different solutions work for different languages, however the ones that allegedly work on Spanish do not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have managed to make it work. I still don't know why this happened, because I've seen other people with the same problem that could solve it with ways that did not work for me. If anyone finds themselves in the same situation, here's what worked for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{listingsutf8, pythonhighlight}
\lstset{ 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breakatwhitespace=false,        
    breaklines=true,        
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
    extendedchars=true, 
    literate= {á}{{\'a}}1 
    {é}{{\'e}}1 
    {í}{{\'i}}1 
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[language=Python]{Programas/data_bindings_RF.py}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that any other combination ***did not*** work for me. I've seen people that made it work just using the `\usepackage{listingsutf8}` package with the

```
\lstset{ 
literate= {á}{{\'a}}1 
    {é}{{\'e}}1 
    {í}{{\'i}}1 
    {ó}{{\'o}}1 
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
}
```

option, but for me it yielded the same result. Same goes for any other combination of packages and settings, I'm not sure why. Good luck!